# Bad file descriptor when polling a websocket in C

Tags: c, sockets

My code uses poll to listen on a socket and receive a message. It is successfully receiving one message from the client and then closing the connection with the error: 'problem accepting fd: Bad file descriptor.' The error remains whether I add the returned file descriptor from accept() to the list of file descriptors checked by poll. This is what confuses me the most: How am I receiving the message if the accept never goes through?

Heres my code:

```
static void poll_add_fd(struct polls_st * polls, int fd) {
    struct pollfd *pfd = &polls->poll_fds[polls->count];
    pfd->fd = fd;
    pfd->events = POLLIN;

    polls->count++;
}

void start_server(struct polls_st * polls, int port_num) {
    polls->count = 0;
    char port_str[16];
    snprintf(port_str, 6, "%d", port_num);
    struct  addrinfo hints;
    memset(&hints, 0 , sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    printf("GETTING addrinfo \n");
    struct addrinfo * res;
    int rc = getaddrinfo(NULL, port_str, &hints, &res);
    if (rc != 0) {
        error("problem getting addrinfo");
    }

    int fd;
    struct addrinfo *r;
    for (r = res; r != NULL; r = r->ai_next) {
        //look for a fd where socket succeeds
        printf("af %d, as %d, ap %d \n", r->ai_family, r->ai_socktype, r->ai_protocol);
        fd = socket(r->ai_family, r->ai_socktype, r->ai_protocol);
        //failed, check next addrinfo
        if (fd == -1) {
            continue;
        }
        printf("setting sock options \n");
        //enable
        int en = 1;
        if (setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &en, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
            error("problem setting socket options");
        }

        printf("setting ioctl \n");
        if (ioctl(fd, FIONBIO, (char *) &en) == -1) {
            error("problem with ioctl");
        }

        printf("binding \n");
        if (bind(fd, r->ai_addr, r->ai_addrlen) == 0) {
            //success!
            break;
        } else {
            error("problem binding");
        }

        //failed
        close(fd);
        fd = -1;
    }

    if (!r) {
        error("problem binding to any adddrinfo");
    }

    printf("listening \n");
    if (listen(fd, SOMAXCONN) == -1) {
        error("problem listening");
    }

    poll_add_fd(polls, fd);
}

void handle_fd(int fd) {
    char buf[32] = {0,};
    int recv_len = 32;
    int nread = recv(fd, buf, recv_len, 0);
    printf("Recieved from client: %s \n", buf);
    close(fd);
    polls->count--;
}

void server_accept(struct polls_st * polls, int pidx) {
    printf("server accepting fd \n");
    int listener_fd = polls->poll_fds[pidx].fd;
    int new_fd = accept(listener_fd, NULL, NULL);
    if (new_fd == -1) {
        error("problem accepting fd");
    } else {
        handle_fd(new_fd);
        //poll_add_fd(polls, new_fd);
    }
}

char* handle_http() {}

void poll_server(struct polls_st * polls) {
    while (1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < polls->count; i++) {
            int pollout = poll(polls->poll_fds, polls->count + 1, 100);
            if (pollout > 0) {
                server_accept(polls, i);
                close(polls->poll_fds[i].fd);
            }
        }
    }
}

void end_server() {

}
```

Comment: You call `poll()` with `polls->count + 1`. Why `+1`? Why do you call `poll()` in `for` loop?

Comment: There's one and only one thing that causes this error, and that is: the file descriptor number you told it to accept from isn't a real file descriptor. That means `polls->poll_fds[pidx].fd` is something completely different from what you think it is. Please check.

Comment: Documenting your code with the intend of what the code should do would help. Then you might realize that you close the listener socket in `poll_server`  immediately after accepting a client from it - which means that it will be invalid when calling `accept` again on it. But your whole looping in `poll_server` looks severely broken to me - better think again about each of the line you wrote there and document the intention of each line.

Comment: Thanks for the help I fixed the problem. I was closing the listening socket when I needed to be closing the data socket. Honestly probably going to take this post down because it would only confuse anybody with a similar problem.